# Set of languages table to be created in phpmyadmin. Can it be made more efficient? Is it properly normalised?

Tags: sql

I'm currently setting up SQL tables for language listing that will serve as a framework for translation efforts of my web application in the near future.

The tables and fields I've decided to create look like this:

```
Language
--------
Language ID
Language name
Native name

Region
------
Language ID
Region

Active
------
Language ID
Active
```

Language ID would the primary key in both tables.

The active field in the active table simply allows me to know which languages have been been translated (denoted by 1) and which haven't.

Sample data would look something like this:

**Language table**

```
Language ID  Language name   Native name
-----------  -------------   -------------
afr          Afrikaans       Afrikaans
sqi          Albanian        gjuha shqipe
ara          Arabic          العربية
```

**Region table**

```
Language ID  Region 
-----------  -------------   
afr          Africa       
sqi          Eastern Europe
ara          Middle East
```

**Active table**

```
Language ID  Active
-----------  -------------   
afr          0
sqi          1
ara          0
```

There plans to be a fixed number of languages and regions. The languages I plan to add to the database (for later translation use) include (all their codes will be garnered from the ISO 639-2/B column which can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes):

```
Afrikaans
Albanian
Arabic
Belarusian
Bulgarian
Catalan
Chinese (simplified)
Chinese (traditional)
Croatian
Czech
Danish
Dutch
English
Estonian
Esperanto
Filipino
Finnish
French
Galician
German
Greek
Hebrew
Hindi
Hungarian
Icelandic
Indonesian
Irish
Italian
Japanese
Korean
Latvian
Lithuanian
Macedonian
Malay
Maltese
Norwegian
Persian
Polish
Portuguese
Romanian
Russian
Serbian
Slovak
Slovenian
Spanish
Swahili
Swedish
Thai
Turkish
Ukrainian
Vietnamese
Welsh
Yiddish
```

The region categories include:

```
All
Africa 
Middle East
Americas
Asia-Pacific
Eastern Europe
Western Europe
```

My question is now have I fully normalised this table? Can it be normalised any further or made any more efficient. I would appreciate any suggestions before I go about setting it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using languageID as the PK in multiple tables you are not properly normalized.

Is the active table just supposed to indicate if the language is active or not? if so active should just be a field in the language table.

Region table should be regionID, region.

Another table should be added that links a region to a language which would only contain the columns languageID and regionID, the pk should be a combined key of regionID and languageID. This will allow you the ability to extend to better represent the many to many relationship that is language to region.

By Request (and some minor changes I would make):

In you example it's not obvious why you would want a link table, but think of it when you get to "the americas" region,  you actually need to have multiple languages as each country may speak English, Spanish, French or Portuguese. And even when you break it down to a country, Canada would need both French and English. Also Spanish is going to be in multiple regions, Europe and The Americas. The link table will better represent this.

Language ID should be an int, even if the 3 letter abbreviation is unique, Most SQL engines will be able to join on ints faster so your language table should be:

```
Language ID  Language Code  Language name   Native name   Active
-----------  -------------  -------------   ------------  ------
1            afr            Afrikaans       Afrikaans     0
2            sqi            Albanian        gjuha shqipe  1
3            ara            Arabic          العربية
4            spa            Spanish         Espanol       1
5            eng            English         English       1
```

I can't seem to put a 0 in the active field after Arabic, whatever ASCII that squiggle is doesn't play nice, so just imagine that it's there.

Your region table should be simply:

```
Region ID  Region 
---------- -------------   
1          Africa       
2          Eastern Europe
3          Middle East
4          Americas
5          Western Europe
```

Now you want a link table, which would basically be:

```
Region ID  Language ID
---------  -----------
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
4          5
5          4
5          5
```

So you can see this better represents that multiple languages may be used in the same region, and a language may be used in multiple locations.

Comment: The active table just indicates whether a language is active or not. Thank you for the clear answer. I just wanted to ask if you could update your answer to show the new tables you've defined in a similar format to myself. Thanks once again you've helped a ton!

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a reasonable name for the link table?

Comment: Naming really depends on your organizations conventions. Some orgs I've been with have a convention of any link table being `tableA_tableB` some insist on `link_tableA_tableB` replacing "link: with whatever work that org uses to denote a many to many relationship. If your org use underscores to mean other things in your naming conventions you would want to find another character to use. I prefer the first method for its simplicity.